# How to read data from a paginated API and upload it as multipart file to S3 page by page

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to read data from a paginated API , Since the whole data is huge so I want to read one page from paginated API and upload it as multipart file to S3 and then read 2nd page & upload it to S3 and so on.

Could you please let me know if this usecase is achievable through Camel.

If yes, could you please also share little example on how to achieve this.